# SSH key authentication fails because SSH key is changed

Tags: ssh, c#, winscp

Every day every 30 min our WinSCP application run in the server. But suddenly our SSH key is changed – how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You probably confuse *key authentication* with *host key*.

See WinSCP article on [Understanding SSH key pairs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys).

If the host key of your server has changed, then it can mean either that:

- Your server was compromised or your are under [MITM attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) or
- Your server was reinstalled/reconfigured and its host key has changed as a consequence.

You need to contact your server administrator to find out what is going on.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your update

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Comment: I have to communicate with our server team then only confirm it. We have two application to call the WinSCP application on the same server. one application working properly but another one is showed error as SSH key changed. So only had a confusion.